# "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" when trying to upload a file

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis

I have an ASP.NET project based on WebForms that was initially published on Azure server. Just recently I have made the website point to a different custom domain and since then I'm getting this error whenever I try to upload a file. I don't have this issue on my local server though. I'm using a jQuery library "pupload" to publish files. Just soon as I click the "select files" button, I'm redirected to a page where this error is displayed. 
This issue wasn't there before so I figured this might me after I changed the domain. Can someone help me out with this.

Comment: Have you considered the obvious? That permissions aren't set up correctly for the directory you're trying to upload to?

Comment: but how do I change the permission on the server side. In properties I can see "This server does not support changing file permissions"

Comment: If Azure Web Sites doesn't let you change permissions (which I'm not sure about) then upload to the App_Data folder or find another hosting service that allows you to manage your permissions.

Comment: are you using web app or azure storage for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileZilla to change permission for a folder/directory in azure. 
Download your publish profile from portal and connect thru FTP(set the connection in filezilla) and set the permissions.

[image]